# Can I use windows utility installed on Windows system with WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I think the answer to my questions is NO.  But I need to get clarity be certain about this.

EXAMPLE: I have sqlcmd windows utility installed on windows and can use it with command prompt, simply type sqlcmd in command prompt and start typing T-SQL commands such as `sp_databases`;`go` will list the databases.

Next if I want to use WSL bash prompt for doing the same I believe the only way to do so is to first install sqlcmd for Ubuntu from WSL bash and then log in to localhost SQL Server with sqlcmd.

Please share what you know to help me get a better understanding of how to get full benefit of WSL for doing things such as using the sqlcmd command at WSL bash prompt.

Thanks for the help.

I have tried issuing this command at the WSL bash prompt which did not work:
`/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ SQL\ Server/110/Tools/Binn/SQLCMD.EXE`

---

OK I had some success, I needed some getting use to but there is some thing to go off here.  To reiterate my name idea was that if a program such as R or Python is installed in windows I shouldn't have to re-install it in WSL with `sudo apt-get install ...`

So for using the sqlcmd utility the following command at bash worked:
`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C sqlcmd`
This command will let give me a "black line/space" to type in T-SQL commands into.  It gives me some success with my experiment, at first it looks funny since there was no prompt or anything but I just type the command `sp_databases` [enter] `go` [enter] and it does the trick.

Next I wanted to really wanted to test this and tried to run the R (installation that runs when I type `>R` at command prompt).  This is command that worked at bash prompt:
`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C R --no-save`

This was more satisfying as it printed R intro and started the R-shell/prompt, the issue was though (what I immediately noticed) was that if I use the up arrow key to scroll through previous commands its won't work rather `^[[A` is printed on the screen at the prompt.

Next I tried another program Python, at command prompt in windows if I enter `>python` it starts a python with the intro, but at WSL bash prompt when I tried:
`/mnt/c/Windows/System32/cmd.exe /C python` it takes me to blank line but unlike sqlcmd this time a simple python command like `dir()` dose not give back any output.

I would greatly appreciate if someone who knows more about these things could explain to me how I can use the programs already installed in windows with reinstalling them in WSL.
§ So why did the python program not start in WSL like it does at the command-prompt.
§ And in case of R program that did start how would I scroll through previous command if the up arrow key start printing `^[[A`

Thanks for help, hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Yes you can. See [WSL interoperability](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/2016/10/19/windows-and-ubuntu-interoperability/).